# ng-mask angular, edit input cursor move to end

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-mask in my code.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker_cal" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" min-date="startDate" name="{{dobName}}" max-date="endDate" mask="99/99/9999" ng-model="newDate" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions"  on-open-focus="false" />
```

eg. value of text box is "10/01/2015"

when I delete the first char '1' cursor moves to end of textbox.

May i know why?
I do not want to move cursor at end.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/issues maybe you should ask here if you do not find why in the docs

Comment: I logged issue, here is the detail.. https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/issues/78

Comment: Just wanted to check if you were able to resolve this issue? I have the same problem and I cant seem to resolve it

Comment: I am having the similar issue. can any one resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
```